# Add Column in Apache Cassandra

Tags: node.js, cassandra

How to check in node.js that the column does not exist in Apache Cassandra ?

I need to add a column only if it not exists.

I have read that I must make a select before, but if I select a column that does not exist, it will return an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if you're on Cassandra 3.x and up, you'll want to query from the `columns` table on the `system_schema` keyspace:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:system_schema> SELECT * FROm system_schema.columns
     WHERE keyspace_name='stackoverflow'
       AND table_name='vehicle_information'
       AND column_name='name';

 keyspace_name | table_name          | column_name | clustering_order | column_name_bytes | kind    | position | type
---------------+---------------------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+---------+----------+------
 stackoverflow | vehicle_information |        name |             none |        0x6e616d65 | regular |       -1 | text

(1 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can check a column existance using a select query on `system.schema_columns` table.**

Suppose you have the table `test_table` on keyspace `test`. Now you want to check a column `test_column` If exit or not.

Use the below query :

```
SELECT * FROM system.schema_columns WHERE keyspace_name = 'test' AND columnfamily_name = 'test_table' AND column_name = 'test_column';
```

If the above query return a result then the column exist otherwise not.